# ActionScript: Separating child from parent on Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm primarily a C++ programmer trying my hand at Flash and ActionScript3 for game development. I'm finding myself a little confused/constricted by the whole Parent/Child relationship, and was wondering if anybody here could give a little insight.

I'm currently making an Astro Panic clone, where each EnemyShip object also contains an array of EnemyShots. My problem is this: when one of the players' shots collides with an EnemyShip, the ship is supposed to disappear. However, at the moment, if the shot collides with one of a ship's shots, this also causes the entire corresponding EnemyShip (as well as all it's previous shots) to disappear. On top of that, it seems that the entire area between an EnemyShip and it's shot(s) trigger a collision. For example, in the following image, if the player's shot reaches anywhere within the red rectangle, the game will register it as the enemy having been hit:

[image]

Obviously I can't have this, but I'm unsure how to deal with it. Is there any way to separate child objects from parents on the stage, or is that just not how ActionScript works?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would create a clip for all the shots. This means there would be 3 principal clips: the player, the enemies and the shots. This way you could achieve shot-ship and shot-shot interactions.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the model (Ships, Shots, Enemies) from their actual representation. Although a shot might be associated with a ship, the visual representations might share the same parent.

So basically I'm trying to say that you can flat the display hierarchy.